# Fullcalendar - Not able to remove non-saved events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar with externally dragged events. The point is that, based on my business case, I can't save the same event twice. I am handling this on the Model so, when dropping the even A into day 1, it will be successully saved. Model will return the record ID and I will update the event accordingly.

Whenever trying to duplicate an event in DB, Model won't allow that and it will return nil ID (which is correct). So, at this point, I would like to remove the last dropped event.

For some reason, this is not being possible. When trying to delete any of the DB existing events, it perfectlly worke but when I want to do this with the last event, it is not working (through `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` ).

Some of the things I tried where to set the ID to -1 or 999 to the unsaved event and then tried to remove it but that was not successfull. Also, I tried getting all the client events and picking the last one (I checked through console the ID and it was perfect but, when internally getting it, it was undefined), so this didn´t work neither.

```
eventReceive: function(event){
    $.ajax({
            url: "/menus",
                type: "POST",
                data: { menu: {
                        fecha: event.start.format(),
                        food_id: event.foodId
                }},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(resp){
                    event.id = resp.menuId;
                    if(event.id){
                       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                    }
                    else{
                       event.id = -1;
                       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', -1);
                    }
                }
    });            
}
```

Could you kindly help me to solve this?

Thanks and regards.

Alejandro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there are some open issues related to this behaviour I was facing and the fuctionalities I was needing to implement (#2928 & #3252).

As a workaround, I have avoided calling eventReceive method by avoiding using data-event attributes so, I am am handling everything from inside drop method. So, once user drops an event, I first check everything and, in case it is OK, I proceed to renderEvent.

By creating events with the "correct" ID, I am not facing any longer the issue related to the fact that delete was not working fine.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

try using `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);`. The `_id` is whats used for events when they have an id automatically assigned to them, or before they have a database id assigned to them.